# Can loud noise outside a bottle, travel through a closed liquid bottle?

Tags: waves, acoustics

If I am inside a closed liquid bottle, will I be able to hear loud noise outside the bottle?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will. In a sound wave that strikes the bottle wall, part of it will bounce off and away from the bottle and part of it will be transmitted through the wall, and you'll hear it inside. The thicker the wall, the more will bounce off and less will be transmitted.

Comment: *"The thicker the wall, the more will bounce off and less will be transmitted."* Shouldn't the transmission to reflection ratio depend on the shear modulus of the bottle rather than the thickness?

Comment: I assumed the bottle was glass. In general terms, the reflection-to-transmission ratio depends on the mass per unit area of the wall and its stiffness. increasing the thickness increases the mass per unit area.